# I want to count checked checkboxes on datagridview when click on the checkbox not on button click

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, checkbox

I want to count the number of checkboxes that are checked in a datagridview when a checkbox is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
Dim count1 As Integer = 0
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvAtt.Rows
  If row.Cells(1).Value = True Then
    count1 += 1
  End If
Next

txtCnton.Text = count1
```

I've called the above procedure in CellContentClick, CellValueChanged and CellStateChanged but it doesn't count properly.

Comment: Are you sure cell(1) is your checkbox column?  DataGridView columns start at index 0.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'It doesn't count properly'?

Answer (score 4):

There are two likely causes for the count of check boxes being different from what you expect. The most likely is that fact that the value of the check box column lags behind the check box state due to how datagridview editing controls commit their values when they lose focus.

The fix for that is to handle the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event as described [here on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx#Y300)

So your code would become something like:

```
Sub dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged( _
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

    If dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If 
End Sub
```

And you CellValueChangedHander then changes to:

```
Public Sub dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.CellValueChanged

    If dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "CheckBoxes" Then 
        Dim count1 As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvAtt.Rows
            If row.Cells("CheckBoxes").Value IsNot Nothing And row.Cells("CheckBoxes").Value = True Then
                count1 += 1
            End If
        Next

        txtCnton.Text = count1
    End If 
End Sub
```

---

In the code above I also address the second likely cause of an incorrect count. In your code you reference datagridview cells by their index in the cells array. This is almost never the best way to do it. Instead each column has a name that you can use in the indexer.

Comment: I also added a null check on the cell value - I wrote my test code in C# so there may be a couple of syntax errors on things like that - also in C# you need to cast the cell value to a boolean, that might be necessary in VB.Net